# Stoping rails from going back in time when booking?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I made this simple form and I don't want to book back in time. Is there any command which fixes the problem?

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="booking-card p-5 mt-5">
            <h1>Create a new booking!</h1>
              <%= simple_form_for [@listing, @booking] do |f| %>
                <%= f.input :start_date %>
                <%= f.input :end_date %>
                <div class="form-actions">
                  <%= f.button :submit, "Create booking", class:"button-28" %>
                </div>
              <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What problem exactly?  Do you want to validate the start date is not in the past?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the above answer that you should add a Model validation to prevent the database from saving dates in the past.

I see you are using the SimpleForm gem, and they probably have a similar option to the built-in Rails helper.

If you want to add a slightly better user experience, I recommend using a Datetime form field. Rails has lots of built-in Form Helpers, including one to select a [Date input](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/date_field).

With this helper, you can **set the minimum valid date**, so you can prevent users from inputting dates in the past/"back in time".

```
# Example with Rails FormHelper

<%= form_for [@listing, @booking] do |f| %>
     <%= f.date_field :start_date, min: Date.today  %>
     <%= f.date_field :end_date %>
     <div class="form-actions">
         <%= f.submit "Create booking", class:"button-28" %>
     </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [validation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validate) to the booking model.